# xscreensaver on 18.10 MATE - not starting

Tags: mate, xscreensaver

I have this on two machines with the same problem. This has only recently started happening -- last couple weeks or so with frequent if not daily updates.

An 18.04 machine is working fine.

No errors in any logs.

**Requested in comments:**

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep screensaver
ii  libopengl-xscreensaver-perl           0.05-1build4                               amd64        Perl module for writing OpenGL-based XScreenSaver hacks
ii  mate-screensaver-common               1.20.2-1                                   all          MATE screen saver and locker (common files)
ii  xscreensaver                          5.36-1ubuntu1                              amd64        Screensaver daemon and frontend for X11
ii  xscreensaver-data                     5.36-1ubuntu1                              amd64        Screen saver modules for screensaver frontends
ii  xscreensaver-data-extra               5.36-1ubuntu1                              amd64        Extra screen saver modules for screensaver frontends
ii  xscreensaver-gl                       5.36-1ubuntu1                              amd64        GL(Mesa) screen saver modules for screensaver frontends
ii  xscreensaver-gl-extra                 5.36-1ubuntu1                              amd64        Extra GL(Mesa) screen saver modules for screensaver frontends
ii  xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod         5.36-1ubuntu1                              amd64        BSOD screen saver module from XScreenSaver
ii  xscreensaver-screensaver-dizzy        0.3-3                                      all          Graphics demo that makes you dizzy (XScreenSaver hack)
ii  xscreensaver-screensaver-webcollage   5.36-1ubuntu1                              amd64        Webcollage screen saver module from XScreenSaver
```

**Update after removing mate-screensaver**

On one of the 18.10 machines xscreensaver is now working. At some point, for reasons I've forgotten, I'd created a startup desktop file *and* a service file so I removed the startup.

On the other 18.10 machine it is not working.

The situation now:

```
 $ dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep screensaver | grep -v xscreen
 $ 

 $ systemctl --user status xscreensaver
 ● xscreensaver.service - XScreenSaver
    Loaded: loaded (/home/stephen/.config/systemd/user/xscreensaver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-02-03 18:00:25 PST; 14h ago
  Main PID: 1264 (xscreensaver)
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/xscreensaver.service
            └─1264 /usr/bin/xscreensaver -nosplash
```

Answer (score 3):

At first you should remove other screensavers (MATE Screen Saver in your case) from system to prevent interference:

```
sudo apt purge mate-screensaver mate-screensaver-common
```

Then enable XScreenSaver autostart via [`systemd` user's service](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html):

```
systemctl --user enable xscreensaver.service
systemctl --user start xscreensaver.service
```

Note: for debugging you can use `systemctl --user status xscreensaver.service`.

Then wait for timeout and screensaver activation.

Comment: I've added more info to the question. The service was enabled on both machines. I removed the mate screensaver. It was installed to only one of the machines and removing it has not fixed that machine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have clean VM, and I can't reproduce your issue on it. Consider to check system integrity with `debsums`, and/or create clean new user profile and test here...

Comment: Nope. Logged in as other user makes no difference. Oh well. Maybe I'll try switching back to mate-screensaver on this machine. I really just want the blanking.