# 18.10 -- gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, 18.10, libraries, xscreensaver

Make of `xscreensaver-5.42` failing on this error.

```
ximage-loader.c:43:12: fatal error: gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h: No such file or directory
#  include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However `gdk-pixbuf` is installed and apt shows no `gdk-pixbuf-xlib`:

```
$ apt search libgdk-pixbuf
libg3d-plugin-gdkpixbuf/cosmic,now 0.0.8-24 amd64 [installed]
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0/cosmic,now 2.38.0+dfsg-6 amd64 [installed]
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin/cosmic,now 2.38.0+dfsg-6 amd64 [installed]
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common/cosmic,cosmic,now 2.38.0+dfsg-6 all [installed]
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev/cosmic,now 2.38.0+dfsg-6 amd64 [installed]
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-doc/cosmic,cosmic 2.38.0+dfsg-6 all
```

Requested in comments:

```
$ dpkg -S gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:amd64: /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-xlib/gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h
```

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -S gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h` to the question. Also note that errors with headers are not actual for binary packages. Where do you see this message?

Comment: Why do you refer to 5.42? Cosmic has [5.36 in the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/xscreensaver).

Comment: I am having trouble with the 5.36 so am trying the latest from the developer site. I have another question here . https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115332/xscreensaver-on-18-10-mate-not-starting?noredirect=1#comment1841840_1115332

Comment: @N0rbert I've added the full error message to the question.

Comment: I think we need to solve first question first. Installing from source may end with more mess than we have now :)

Comment: I have the same issue, no such file or directory for gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h when building xscreensaver 5.44. I am working on making my own screensaver, so can't use a premade binary package. @StephenBoston did you ever fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to look at the warnings you got in the previous step, when running `./configure` before running `make`. In my case I got a warning to the effect of `warning: while GTK is installed, libxml-2.0 could not be found. Are all required libraries installed?`

A little `apt search`ing revealed I needed to `sudo apt install libxml2-dev`, then I got a similar message for `libglade-2.0`, which was installed with `sudo apt libglade2-dev`. Rerunning `./configure` confirmed the missing libraries were successfully installed, and then `make` ran successfully.

In summary, you probably need to `sudo apt install libxml2-dev libglave2-dev`, but should look at the warnings of the `./configure` script and resolve issues it warns about before running `make`.