# Xscreensaver not working properly

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

I don't understand Linux and sys-admin stuff, but I have installed recently xscreensaver Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS as described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/114027/how-to-add-screensavers-to-ubuntu-12.04/) and I have followed all the steps. If I lock the screen with Cntrl+Alt+L then the xscreensaver starts. But If I wait for the screen to time out, it just goes blank black like the gnome-screensaver does, despite that I have gnome-screensaver installed. Curiously, when I type `locate screensaver.desktop` I get:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-screensaver.desktop
/home/nestor/.config/autostart/xscreensaver.desktop
```

I was afraid to delete the `gnome-screensaver.desktop` file, so I out commented everything in it. Still, same problem persists.

If after a restart I type `xscreensaver -nosplash` I get:

```
xscreensaver: 18:39:29: already running on display :0 (window 0x1a000de)
```

I guess, this is good and excludes the possibility that screensaver just doesn't get automatically started on start-up.

Then I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1115344/771488) and I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gnome-screensaver
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gnome-screensaver
systemctl --user enable xscreensaver.service
systemctl --user start xscreensaver.service
```

After the last command I got the message:

```
Failed to start xscreensaver.service: Unit xscreensaver.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See user logs and 'systemctl --user status xscreensaver.service' for details.
```

The referred log says:

```
● xscreensaver.service - XScreenSaver
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)
   Active: inactive (dead)

апр 03 18:07:22 nestor-Eve-V systemd[1492]: /usr/lib/systemd/user/xscreensaver.service:5: Executable path is not absolute: xscreensaver
апр 03 18:07:22 nestor-Eve-V systemd[1492]: xscreensaver.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit xscreensaver.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
```

This suggests the problem is "Executable path is not absolute", so I opened the file `/usr/lib/systemd/user/xscreensaver.service` and it contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=XScreenSaver
[Service]
ExecStart=xscreensaver
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Do I have to type there an absolute path? Any ideas how can I enable screensaver to work properly? thanks

Comment: 19.04 has passed its end of public support. As per https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic we can assist with upgrading to a current version.

Comment: @K7AAY My bad, I checked with `lsb_release -a` and my version is 18.04.4 LTS. Do you have any ideas regarding the problem and can you upvote it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question, @NeStack.

This error message seems clear:

```
systemd[1492]: /usr/lib/systemd/user/xscreensaver.service:5: Executable path is not absolute: xscreensaver
```

So I opened the file with `sudo vim /usr/lib/systemd/user/xscreensaver.service` and saw this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=xscreensaver
```

I replaced it with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/xscreensaver`, after which `systemctl --user start xscreensaver.service` no longer gives an error.
`